# Вопросительные местоимения

Tags: склонение, местоимения

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант употребления правильный (от нач. формы мест. **КАКОВ**):
1) "Каковы будут последствия этого решения?"
2) "Каковыми будут последствия этого решения?"

Answer (score 1):

Обе формы допустимы, это разные падежи - именительный и творительный. 
Творительный сейчас вообще в подобных и многих других выражениях с "быть" уступает место именительному ("сравните: "я был инженером" -> "я был инженер, я был богатым" -> "я был богатый" -> "я был богат"), правда имеются некоторые смысловые оттенки по линии "состояние - качество", они не очень здесь существенны.

В целом же творительный падеж (форма "каковыми") прочно держит позиции только в канцелярской речи и в оборотах "Каковыми/таковыми являются", т. е. в настоящем времени с опущенным сказуемым "есть" и его заменителями ("являться", "находится" и т. д.).

В Вашем случае гораздо естественнее форма ***"Каковыми будут последствия этого решения?"***.

Answer (score 1):

> *1) [**Каковы будут последствия**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-RDzVv-_PIj8ywOs-KIo#q=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks) этого решения?*
>
> *2) [**Каковыми будут последствия**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=VBHzVv-QM8nm6ATN6Y3YCw#q=%22%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks) этого решения?*

Возможны оба варианта, но первый **значительно** более распространён . Я бы предпочёл его:

***Каковы будут последствия этого решения?***